# Manual AJAX Trigger with jQuery Isotope in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, jquery-isotope

I am using [jQuery Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) with Wordpress and so far it all works well. I am now attempting to add a "load more posts' button after X amount of posts, that when clicked will fetch the next page of posts and append them to isotope container. The way it currently works is by just loading `http://localhost/page/2` and it does show the correct posts.

Basically it should work like this plugin http://www.problogdesign.com/wordpress/load-next-wordpress-posts-with-ajax/ except it should append them to the isotope container.

I have searched and searched for a solution and tried editing the above plugin with no joy. I managed to get the above plugin working but without the isotope feature, combining them isotope caused issues 'appending' them and didn't extend the container or animate them masonry like the other posts. I basically need infinite scrolling that is activated manually with a click of a link. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Say after you have fired ajax request and get result from it which is appended to the container (of `isotope`), you will need to call `reloadItems` method and then call `isotope` method once again to layout all items.

```
$.post(url, data, function(response) {
    $container.append(response);
    $container.isotope('reloadItems');
    $container.isotope();
});
```

I am assuming that you are using latest version of `isotope` i.e version 2.

REF: `reloadItems` method docs: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html#reloaditems

Answer (score 0):

It helped for me to use a trigger of the ajaxComplete event:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
  // ...
  $container.isotope('reloadItems');
  $container.isotope({filter: filters});
  // ...
});
```

N.B. Please note, we should invoke the isotope() method after reloading with the same params as it was before.